# Problem after trying to use opencv cuda build

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

so i have been trying to install opencv cuda for 2 days and i'm getting weird problem. If i open anaconda prompt, it says i dont have opencv and i have python 3.11 while in windows command prompt, it says i have opencv 4.8.0 and another python version 3.10.

i used to have opencv 4.8 before i start playing around opencv cuda and i deleted it using pip uninstall before doing the Cmake thing.

so my questions are:
1- How to completly wipe opencv from my system so i can install it correctly?
2- i'm doing cmake build with cuda 11.2 and opencv 4.9. my graphics card is gtx1660ti mobile, are these versions compatible to run opencv on cuda?
3- do i need to do pip install before i do the cmake build or the whole process will be taken care of by cmake?

i'm running tensorflow on cuda and no problem so far but i need opencv to run on cuda cause i need much more processing power for my image detection model than my cpu can provide.

T[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cI1h.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2aYn.png)

tried to uninstall opencv and reinstall but same problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the package manually? You can find it's location using either python -m pip show opencv, or you can check all paths with sys.path (after importing sys). You can also try print opencv.__file__

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did manage to delete everything but when I compiled the OpenCV from the source I can't import it. it keeps saying not defined. any tips to solve this?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full error message and the steps you took. PS: I'm not sure if opencv 4.9 will be compatible with CUDA 11.2. It's quite an old release. Have you thought about installing a newer version of CUDA? E.g. 12.1 - 12.3?